# Certificate to read Digitally Signed Emails in EWS

Tags: c#, vb.net, exchangewebservices, smime

I am trying to read digitally signed emails in EWS. Specifically I am interested in the file attachments in the email. I am using the following code with no success:

```
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms();
signedCms.Decode(filebyte)
```

Where filebyte is the smime.p7m attachment.

I get the error "ASN1 bad tag value 
met." on the second line of the code.

Can anybody help me figure out the issue? Am I missing a certificate on the machine that runs the code? Or is the certificate already in the smime.p7m? Am I not supposed to pass smime.p7m attachment to decode?

Comment: Are you sure its a good message ? The MSDN page says that it should throw a CryptographicException if there is a decryption problem.

Comment: I believe  "ASN1 bad tag value met." is the message in the CryptographicException. So yes it is CryptographicException that I am getting with that message.